# Remapping Menu/Context Menu key to Option - Karabiner Not Working

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, keybindings, karabiner

I'm using macOS BigSur with a Windows Keyboard - Drevo Tyrfind v2. I want to remap the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key that's on the right side of the keyboard next to the control button to the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key.

I'm using Karabiner v 13.2 however in the event viewer the app doesn't show/detect any Keyboard events even though I've allowed the INPUT observation for all Karabiner processes under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** section.

Could someone help me remap the menu key to <kbd>Opt</kbd> key?